# Unable to use terminal after launching VSCode

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I've just got a new laptop (Windows 11), so I've had to re-install all of my software applications.

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 and VS Code, I'm now running into a problem. When running `code .` from the Ubuntu terminal VS Code opens, but I'm no longer able to use the Ubuntu terminal whilst VS Code is open.

This never happened on my old laptop, and it's annoying that I have to close VS Code every time I want to run `git add` or `pip install`.

I've added VS Code to PATH in my environment variables, and I've tried comparing the launch settings.json between my old and new laptop but nothing leaps out as impacting the terminal.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add a trailing `&` to the call to start VS Code [as a background process](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/):

   ```
   code . &
   ```
2. Use VS Code's [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) via the top menu `Terminal -> New Terminal`.

Comment: Legend, thank you! The top one is what I was after, so it runs as a background process.